# concatenate heredocs with output of a command

Tags: bash, concatenation, cat, heredoc

I want to write into a file with a pre-HEREDOC, a post-HEREDOC and in the middle I want the output of a command. Is that possible in a concise way?

I can do

```sh
(
    echo '#ifndef FOO_H'
    echo '#define FOO_H'
    echo
    echo

    sed foo.c -e '/=\|}/d' -e 's/ {/;/'

    echo '#endif'
) > foo.h
```

But I don't like it, because I t is intended and uses many echos.

I want to try to use `cat` and HEREDOCS:

My idea is

```sh
cat > foo.h <<EOF
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H


EOF
sed foo.c -e '/=\|}/d' -e 's/ {/;/'
<<EOF2

#endif
EOF2
```

But I don't know how get them pipe syntactially into cat.

I also tried using different file descriptors. Telling `cat` to concatenate `fd=3 .. 5` and having `fd=3` the HEREDOC before, `fd=4` the output from `sed` and `fd=5` the second HEREDOC, but the problem is that `5<<EOF` does not go to `cat`.

```sh
cat >"${dir}/foo.h" /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/4 /dev/fd/5 4<(
  sed foo.c -e '/=\|}/d' -e 's/ {/;/'
) \
  3<<EOF
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

EOF
5<<EOF

#endif
EOF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat <<EOF > foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

$(sed -e '/=\|}/d' -e 's/ {/;/' foo.c)

#endif
EOF
```

Comment: Why change `EOF` to `==MY=FOO=CODE==` ? While both will work, `EOF` is pretty standard for heredocs, and I'm not sure `==MY=FOO=CODE==` adds much regarding to readability :)

Comment: @Aserre Use what ever you want.. It's jsust a DELIMITER!

Comment: Yeah, I know, your answer is correct whichever delimiter you chose to use (I upvoted it), so it's pretty much opinion based. I'm just pointing out that `EOF`, or even `EOD` is considered the "standard" for heredocs

Comment: @Aserre i changed to EOF just for you ;)